# Match Two Select Statements for Comparison

Tags: sql

I have two sql views with the following select statements:

1.

```
 select SUBSTRING(UpdatedColumn,3, 9) as [PartialSearch] from [Database_Name].[dbo].[Table]
```

2.

```
select SUBSTRING(OldColumn,3, 9) as [PartialSearchOnLiveTable] from [Same_Database_Name].[dbo].[DifferentTable]
```

Both these views only return 1 column respectively. Now I want to compare values in the first view against values in the second view and return the UpdatedColumn data where a match is not found.

I have considered using comparison operators but just can't seem to get what I want since according to my logic, I will have to specify the conditional checking of the views against each other in the where clause and sql does not permit that. Also, a UNION/UNION ALL will just give me the result set of all the records. Which is something that I don't want.

Lastly, I had a look at [Combine two select statements for date comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020441/combine-two-select-statements-for-date-comparison) and its not what I'm looking for.

Practically, View 1 returns :

```
abcxxxxxx
dokjfhxxx
cmodxxxxx
wuysxxxxx
aaallooxx
```

View 2 Returns:

```
xdsffsafa
xxxxhjsks
ajdhxxxxx
cmodxxxxx
xxxxxx12s
skskshdki
aaallooxx
```

From the output we see that there are two matches. That of

```
aaallooxx
cmodxxxxx
```

That's the output I am looking for. Any suggestions?

Comment: INTERSECT, if your dbms support it. Or do EXISTS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `intersect`, set operator between the two queries. So it prints only the common rows present in the two queries.

```
select SUBSTRING(OldColumn,3, 9) as [PartialSearchOnLiveTable] from [Same_Database_Name].[dbo].[DifferentTable]
intersect --Set Operation between the two queries
select SUBSTRING(UpdatedColumn,3, 9) as [PartialSearch] from [Database_Name].[dbo].[Table]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This seems to be the quickest and most efficient way of doing it. And I now what to find the ones which don't match. Using 'NOT EXISTS' operator does not seem like the way to go.. what would be the opposite to the INTERSECT operator?

Comment: `TableA EXCEPT TableB`, gives records present in A which are not present in B (For SQL Server). You may use `MINUS` for oracle.

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUBSTRING(UpdatedColumn,3, 9) as [PartialSearch] 
from [Database_Name].[dbo].[Table] a 
INNER JOIN [Database_Name].[dbo].[Diff_Table] b 
ON a.SUBSTRING(UpdatedColumn,3, 9) = b.SUBSTRING(OldColumn,3, 9)
```

You can just join them normally using your substring outputs

Comment: it can't seem to recognize the aliases for some odd reason. Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Cannot find either column "a" or the user-defined function or aggregate "a.SUBSTRING", or the name is ambiguous.